# allocation of objects in memory mapped file

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-mapped-files, solaris-10

I have a structure as below:

```
struct 
{
   int x;
   char szT[200];
   int y;
} XX;
```

I have a file that stores several of these XX objects, written through fwrite call.
Now when I read the file as a memory mmaped file using mmap, I use as:

```
// sz = size of the file in bytes
// fd = file descriptor of the file opened through fopen in O_RDWR mode
char *p = (char *) mmap(0,sz,PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,MAP_SHARED,fd,0);
```

And store the contents in a vector as:

```
vector<XX *> av;
unsigned int N = (sz / sizeof(XX));
av.resize(N);
XX *px = (XX*) p;
int i;
for(i=0;i<N;++i) {
    px[i] = p + i;
}
```

And later access vector av for the XX objects.
When I clear the vector using

```
av.clear();
```

do I need to call destructor of all XX objects as well or they would be automatically destroyed? Or not required because this is a vector of pointers, then my question is also when I do `px[i] = p + i;` as shown above, is XX constructor called? Does mmap allocate space, how much?
The use of av may appear as extra burden. But this is a part of a legacy code and need to optimize within the constraints. The purpose of av is to provide easy access to the file contents in terms of elements within the structure. Because contents of vector can be accessed through iterator

Comment: Why do you need a vector of pointers? Looks like meaningless work and wasted memory to me.

Comment: What is the purpose of `av` in the code shown?

Comment: Also what do you think that the for loop is achieving?

Comment: You are absolutely right, but  this is part of legacy code, need to optimize within the constraints